# How to tarball a directory without carrying over /path/to/folder?

Tags: command-line-interface, tar

Example command:
`$ tar -cvjf destination.tar.bz2 /path/to/folder/source`

I'd like the final `destination.tar.bz2`, when extracted, to not include a `/path/to/folder/` file directory. It seems inefficient to extract the tarball and then mv the contents of `/path/to/folder/source` to a different directory.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681595/tar-a-directory-but-dont-store-full-absolute-paths-in-the-archive

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`tar -C /path/to/folder -cvjf /path/for/acrhive.tar.bz2 source`

`-C` (uppercase) means 'change directory', so your file specification becomes relative to the path provided with `-C`

Comment: Bear in mind that the path you provide for "source" is relative to the "-C". Like, that's what @thinice wrote, it's just that if you still provide an absolute path instead of relative even when using "-C", you don't get the desired result.

Answer (score 5):

There are **many** ways to accomplish that, but this is probably the simplest:

```
cd /path/to/folder
tar -cvjf /past/to/destination.tar.bz2 source
```

Comment: I'm partial to 'cd /path/to/folder && tar cjf /path/to/destination.tar.bz2 source'